# error in publish.yml to publish my site on GitHub (html)

Tags: python, github, jupyter, workflow, quarto

I'm trying to publish my html document on GitHub but when I change the document it doesn't change on GitHub. So I did a workflow and a `publish.yml` document and write this :

```yaml
on:
 workflow_dispatch:
 push:
    branches: main

name: Quarto Publish

jobs:
  build-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      contents: write
    steps:
      - name: Check out repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Set up Quarto
        uses: quarto-dev/quarto-actions/setup@v2

      - name: Render and Publish
        uses: quarto-dev/quarto-actions/publish@v2
        with:
          target: gh-pages
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

I have this error :

```
Jupyter is not available in this Python installation.
50
Install with python3 -m pip install jupyter
51

52
ERROR: Error
53
    at renderFiles (file:///opt/quarto/bin/quarto.js:86658:30)
54
    at async render (file:///opt/quarto/bin/quarto.js:90681:21)
55
    at async renderForPublish (file:///opt/quarto/bin/quarto.js:121247:33)
56
    at async renderForPublish (file:///opt/quarto/bin/quarto.js:109089:24)
57
    at async Object.publish4 [as publish] (file:///opt/quarto/bin/quarto.js:120459:26)
58
    at async publishDocument (file:///opt/quarto/bin/quarto.js:121349:38)
59
    at async publish5 (file:///opt/quarto/bin/quarto.js:121445:132)
60
    at async doPublish (file:///opt/quarto/bin/quarto.js:121401:13)
61
    at async publishAction (file:///opt/quarto/bin/quarto.js:121412:9)
62
    at async Command.fn (file:///opt/quarto/bin/quarto.js:121389:9)
63
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I try to change the file in :

```yaml
on:
 workflow_dispatch:
 push:
    branches: main

name: Quarto Publish

jobs:
  build-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      contents: write
    steps:
      - name: Check out repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Set up Quarto
        uses: quarto-dev/quarto-actions/setup@v2

      - name: Install Python and Dependencies
        uses: actions/setup-python@v4
        with:
          python-version: '3.10'
          cache: 'pip'
      - run: pip install jupyter
      - run: pip install -r requirements.txt

      - name: Render and Publish
        uses: quarto-dev/quarto-actions/publish@v2
        with:
          target: gh-pages
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

and I have this error :

```
Error: No file in /home/runner/work/Crowdsourcing/Crowdsourcing matched to [**/requirements.txt or **/pyproject.toml], make sure you have checked out the target repository
```

I don't have a `requirements.txt` file and I don't need one so I don't know how I can do to fix it.

Comment: sorry for the text, I try to put this in a code block but I'm not sure to understand how it works so it's a mess

Answer (score 2):

You need to checkout the code before installing pip requirements.txt  hence it is throwing the error message.(Assuming you have requirements.txt in your remote repository)

```yaml
- uses: actions/checkout@v3
  with:
    fetch-depth: 0
```

use above github action to checkout the code base before performing  `pip install -r requirements.txt`

If you don't want to install dependencies inside requirements.txt or it is not needed then please remove that line ( `- run: pip install -r requirements.txt`) in your workflow.